# Cocos2d Assert failed: reference count should be greater than 0

Tags: cocos2d-x, sprite, game-engine

Im trying to add a public node in another with touchBegan but i get this error by console

```
Assert failed: reference count should be greater than 0
Assertion failed: (_referenceCount > 0), function retain, file /Users/user/Desktop/App/cocos2d/cocos/base/CCRef.cpp, line 93.
```

This is my code:

.h

```
cocos2d::Node* node1 = cocos2d::Node::create();
cocos2d::Node* node2 = cocos2d::Node::create();
```

.ccp

```
bool HelloWorld::onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
 node1->removeAllChildren();
 node1->addChild(node2);
return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're createing node in .h file? That's not gonna work. Do it in init fuction:

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    if (!Layer::init())
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto node1 = Node::create();
    auto node2 = Node::create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.h

```
class HelloWorld
{
...

Node *node1;
Node *node2;
}
```

.cpp

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    if (!Layer::init())
    {
        return false;
    }

   node1 = Node::create();
   addChild(node1);
}

bool HelloWorld::onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
 node1->removeAllChildren();
 node2 = Node::create();
 node1->addChild(node2);
return true
}
```